# WebView Google Maps panning/dragging in Qt5

Tags: webview, qtwebkit, qt5

I'm currently porting an application from Qt 4 to Qt 5 and experiencing some problems with the **WebView** QML element.  I can successfully load a Google Maps webpage into a WebView, however the page only responds to single or double-clicks; attempting to click-drag the map view to pan the visible area has no effect.

Previously, with the Qt 4 version of my code, I used the 'pressGrabTime: 0' WebView property and spoofed the user agent in order to achieve the click-drag functionality.

I have been referred to the source code for the *MiniBrowser* example supplied with Qt 5, which appears to generate mock touch events in order to enable the required functionality.  However, the example code makes use of a number of private frameworks which I would ideally like to avoid having to incorporate into my own code.

Can anyone shed some light on why the WebView element does not respond to click-drag events, and suggest a way of overcoming this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your question, but maybe I can give you another solution to your problem.

Google maps gives you map tiles based on long/lat & zoom level, maybe you can make a side request to the neighboring tiles, and stitch them together into the image you want.

Check out tangogps/foxtrotgps, it is open source so you can see what they have done to make the google maps tiles work with there software.